# Create an object from other objects with exact properties in the type signature

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'm not sure how to phrase it.  Basically I want a function that will combine any number of objects based on their properties of `key` and `value` and return the exact type.  It's better to show what I mean:

```
const objA = { key: 'a', value: 123 };
const objB = { key: 'b', value: 'a string' };
const result = combine(objA, objB);
/*
desired type result:
{ 
  a: number,
  b: string,
}
*/

function combine(...args: any[]): any {
  return args.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably leave your implementation signature as-is and add a single [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to describe the rather involved type manipulation you're trying to represent:

```
function combine<KV extends Array<{ key: P; value: any }>, P extends keyof any>(
  ...args: KV
): { [K in KV[number]["key"]]: Extract<KV[number], { key: K }>["value"] };
function combine(...args: any[]): any {
  return args.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

So this is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function, with two type parameters `KV` and `P`.  `P` is basically just a generic key type, and could be done away with and replaced with `string | number | symbol` (`keyof any` is another way of saying that) except for a wrinkle I'll mention in a little bit.  For now, just think of it as "some key type".

`KV` is an array of objects with a `key` property of some key type, and a `value` property of any type at all.  This is the type of the `args` rest argument.

The return type is where all the fun happens.  It is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) whose keys are `KV[number]["key"]`.  `KV[number]` means "what you get when you index into `KV` with a `number` key", i.e., the elements of the `KV` array.  And `KV[number]["key"]` becomes a union of all the `key` properties of those elements.  For each key `K`, the property value will be `Extract<KV[number], {key: K}>["value"]`.  `Extract<KV[number], {key: K}>` means: take the elements of `KV` and [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) just those whose `key` property is `K`.  And given that, we look up its `"value"` property.

Meaning: the return type is an object whose keys are the `key` properties from `args` elements, and whose value types are the `value` properties from `args` corresponding to each key.

---

So let's make sure this works:

```
const result1 = combine(
  { key: "a", value: 123 },
  { key: "b", value: "a string" }
); 
// const result1: {a: number; b: string};
```

Looks good.

Note that If `P` were removed from the signature and replaced with just `keyof any`, the above type of `result1` would have been just `{[k: string]: string | number}`... because the keys `"a"` and `"b"` would have been widened from the desired [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) to just `string`.  Using `P` as a separate type parameter is a trick that gives the compiler a [hint to keep the key types as string literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) when the type of `KV` is inferred.

Relatedly, `objA` and `objB` as you defined them would also result in `{[k: string]: string | number}`, because the compiler has no hint that you care about `"a"` and `"b"` as anything but `string`.  There are different ways to avoid such widening; one is to use [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions), as in:

```
const objA = { key: "a" as const, value: 123 };
const objB = { key: "b" as const, value: "a string" };
```

which gives you your desired result in `combine()`:

```
const result = combine(objA, objB);
// const result: {a: number; b: string}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: You are a wizard!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a static type definition from a dynamic list of key/value pairs? Or do you want an object representation?

If the second option:

```js
function combine(...args: Array<{key: string, value: any}>): Array<string, string> {
  return args.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.key] = typeof(obj.value);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```